# ViewPager - vertical and horizontal implementation at the same time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, sliding

Is it possible to do sliding among Fragments horizontally as well as vertically in the same FragmentActivity?

Let's say I have 4 fragments A, B, C and D.
I want A and B to be able to slide between each other horizontally and A with C or B with D vertically.

Is it even possible? Or is there any other way to achieve this using Fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just built a [DoubleFragmentViewpager library](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/DoubleFragmentViewpager) that should do what you want.

I just tried it myself so maybe it's not that robust but you could give it a try.

If you can afford not using fragments, I also recommand you the juliome10's [DoubleViewPager](https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager).